# Spring MVC : adding securityConfig.xml along with dispatcherContext.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, web.xml

I come across this code in my web.xml but I don't understand how to add `securityConfig.xml` to the classpath along with `dispatcherContext.xml`

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>classpath:dispatcherContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

can anyone please give me some suggestion

**UPDATE**

when i include `<import resource="classpath:securityConfig.xml" />` in `dispatcherContext.xml` like as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

   <import resource="classpath:securityConfig.xml" />
```

I am getting the below Exception

```
ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:securityConfig.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [dispatcherContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [securityConfig.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [securityConfig.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use import within the root context definiton (dispatcherContext.xml in yr case) file :

```
<!-- Load spring security related configuration -->
<import resource="classpath:securityConfig.xml"/>
```

But you can supply mutiple by putting a space btween the file names :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>dispatcherContext.xml securityConfig.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: But what about the classpath, `classpath:` is missing in `<param-value>dispatcherContext.xml securityConfig.xml</param-value>`

Comment: but got exception --> `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/securityConfig.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/securityConfig.xml]`

Comment: i have placed the `securityConfig.xml` in the same place where `dispatcherContext.xml` is been placed i.e within the resource folder

Comment: `dispatcherContext.xml` is picking up if i remove the `dispatcherContext.xml`

Comment: the convential way is to reference other files from within the xml file, or java class if doing java based conf. Mutlple context definition in the web.xml would imply different applications, but thats not actually what you want.

Comment: where should i import the security file, is it within the dispatcher

Comment: yes , more commnoly called applicationContext or rootContext or a variation of.

Comment: now `Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:securityConfig.xml]`

Comment: Got its with the missing of spring-security-cobfig.jar...now its working